# Algebra: manipulation of variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I apologise maths is not my strong point, there are 2 ways to isolate `n`

How do I know which is the correct way:

Correct equation:

${n={cv}}$

---

way 1 divide by `n`

${c=\frac{n}{v}}$

${\frac{c}{n}=\frac{n}{vn}}$

${\frac{c}{n}={v}}$

${\frac{c}{nc}=\frac{v}{c}}$

### ${{n}=\frac{v}{c}}$

Way 2 multiply by `v`:

${c=\frac{n}{v}}$

${cv=\frac{nv}{v}}$

${n={cv}}$

Comment: In the first way, you start with $n=cv$ and end up with $n=$ something else. This should be a sign that something is wrong.

Comment: damn sorry it wasn't meant to be that @Sandejo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional info so OP understands the language.

When you write:

$\require{cancel}$

$${\frac{c}{n}=\frac{n}{vn}}$$

and you do this:

$${\frac{c}{n}=\frac{\cancel{n}}{v\cancel{n}}}\Rightarrow{\frac{c}{n}=\frac{1}{v}}$$

Then you didn't divide by $n$.
You **cancelled out** $n$ because it was in the numerator and the denominator as well.
The equation does not change when you do this.

**Bonus tip:**
Say you have equation $a=bc$

When you divide the only thing you mustn't forget is to state that the variable you divide by cannot be zero. So if you divide by $b$:

$$b\neq0$$

And if you divide by $c$

$$c\neq0$$

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, so this is what happens:
${c=\frac{n}{v}}\Rightarrow{cv=\frac{nv}{v}\Rightarrow{{(n)(1)=cv}}}$

Comment: This is correct, yes.

Comment: you’ve been quite kind thank you for the info in the chat, most people don’t give a dumbass like me the time of day, I want to learn but there are some things I don’t notice and I need the help of someone else, would you be willing to chat sometimes about queries I have? @LordCommander

Comment: Don't call yourself a dumbass. We all came from there! Sure i would!

Here's an advice: don't be discouraged when you get stuck on a problem, math is supposed to be hard. Try to pander over a problem for a longer period of time before posting. While you struggle, your brain actually learns the material.
Best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac c{cv}=\dfrac 1v$, not $v$ (which you have in the first way)

---

Addendum in response to question edit:

$\dfrac nv=c\implies\dfrac nc=v\implies \dfrac {nc}c=vc\implies n=vc$

($\dfrac nc=\dfrac c{cv}$ is not correct, nor is $\dfrac{nc}c=\dfrac vc$, nor $n=\dfrac vc$.)

Comment: sorry I had wrote the wrong equation in way 1 can you please take a look again @J.WTanner

Comment: @J.WTanner, can you explain why you can't divide by `c`?

Comment: Oh god I done it wrong again please review after my edit

Comment: from ${\frac{c}{n}=\frac{n}{vn}}$ to ${\frac{c}{n}={v}}$

Comment: Do you see where you made the mistake?

Comment: oh ffs I done it wrong again, the jatexx syntax really confuses me can you review again? @LordCommander

Comment: @Nickotine to be honest i don't see what your original problem was. Could you write that one down so we could walk through it til the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120599/discussion-between-lord-commander-and-nickotine).

Comment: I just have 1 last question: 

${n=\frac{1}{vc}\Rightarrow{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{vc}}\Rightarrow{\frac{1}{n}=vc}$ |
I’m used to the concept of what you do on 1 side of the equation you do to the other side.

However it seems when you invert that the rules are different, can you please clarify?

@LordCommander

Comment: @Nickotine what you got here is correct, for example if $n=\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{\;\;\frac{1}{5}\;\;}=5$

Comment: Notice how i put a 'big' division sign there, to differentiate between $1/(1/5)$ and $(1/1)/5$. Our case is the former (obviously) because we divide by $n=1/5$

Comment: So inverting like this really is the right answer? ${n=\frac{1}{vc}\Rightarrow{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\dfrac{1}{1}}{vc}}\Rightarrow{\frac{1}{n}=vc}$ | See I’m trying to apply this concept in an equation and it just doesn’t work, perhaps we could chat about it later for the equation I’m trying to use this on, the question is ‘bond breaking energy’ something, you’ll find it on my profile, always appreciate your help @LordCommander

Comment: @Nickotine your MathJax is off but yes, that's correct, i think in your post there is a different problem

Comment: I’m still getting used to mathJax.... only been using it for maybe 3 or 4 days

Comment: Say you have: ${q=\frac{\dfrac{x}{y}}{z}}$
whats the process to get rid of z? Remember I’m bad at maths... @LordCommander

Comment: @Nickotine what do you mean get rid of? if in an equation there is only one pc. of $z$ then usually there is no way to get rid of it :)

Comment: say you have $z=z\cdot a$ then you can just divide by $z$ and it will fall out to give you $1=a$_____________($\cdot$ means multiplication)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062360/using-dimesional-analysis-to-get-planck-s-lambda-equation-with-avogadro-s  I thought ai’d just ask this as a seperate question @LordCommander