# How Do Mathematicians ‘make up’ or perhaps more correctly ‘derive’ equations

Tags: linear-algebra, education

I know this is definitely a thing otherwise we wouldn’t have equations.

What are the methods for making up an equation from scratch and from making up an equation from an existing equation?

The only way I have been able to do this is using dimensional analysis and I’d like to learn other ways, if you want to see an example of me using dimensional analysis to ‘make up an equation’ see [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062360/using-dimensional-analysis-to-get-planck-s-lambda-equation-with-avogadro/4066065?noredirect=1#comment8400896_4066065).

How for example can you make up the following without experimentation:

Speed equation:
$$\text v=\frac{\text d}{\text t}$$

Density equation:
$$\text p=\frac{\text m}{\text v}$$

After seeing some answers, how do you make up an equation for a definition? @littleO tells me the velocity equation is a definition and I’d like to know how the guy who made the equation went about it.

Or how do you look at a square and come up with a quadratic equation?

Are there any equations you can make up without experimentation?

If this is too general, specific examples are welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121020/discussion-on-question-by-nickotine-how-do-mathematicians-make-up-or-perhaps-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need to remember, that "equations" are nothing more than formalized language. Before people "invented" equations, they argued with words, which today are a pain to read. Here is Newtons Second Law (summed up nicely in $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$):

> The alteration of motion is ever proportional to the motive force impressed; and is made in the direction of the right line in which that force is impressed.

So math, as you may learned it in school may be terrifying because much teaching is done using the formal set of rules, rather than words. However, what is important are the ideas that are conveyed either with words, or with the equations. To go from one equation to another, we simply use clever *tautologies*, definitions of certain variables, that replace other variables (in the $v$ example, $\frac{d}{s}$)

Let's do a basic example: Let's assume all you own is a bag of apples, of unknown quantity. Now let's say I give you an apple. How many apples do you have?

*Clearly*, you have 1 apple, plus the amount of apples in the bag, no? So now let's define some variables:

- $A$ is the amount of apples you have *after* I give you an apple
- $b$ is the amount of apples there are in the bag.

Going off of these *definitions*, we can say the following:

$$A=1+b$$

This makes sense, no? You *definitely* have one apple, in addition to those that are in the bag. Furthermore, you cannot have more apples, because we assumed that you don't have anything else (note how we are assuming things). Et voilà, you have an equation with certain dimensional values!

Now let's get funkier. Let's say that the amount of apples in the bag is equal to the amount of apples my grandmother has. So if:

- $g$ is the amount of apples my grandmother has

then you *know*

$$g=b$$

Now you see, that there is no need for you to know *explicitly* and *only* how many apples are in the bag. If you know the amount of apples my grandmother has, you know the amount of apples in your bag. To formalize this in equation form, this:
$$A=1+b$$

becomes this:
$$A=1+g$$

because $g=b$. Now you have another equation. Clearly, you can own trucks with apples, divisions of apples, square root of the amount of apples that the CEO of ExampleFirm makes in USD per year, per store location, etc. You can formalize what I'm saying, but as you can tell, just because you have an equation, doesn't mean it's correct. That's why you need to *assume* that certain things are the case, in order for the equation to make any real world sense.

You can graph virtually *any* equation. It might be a boring graph (all variables defined), but remember: Even a graph is just a tautology, i.e. a way to convey the information that is in the equation (which in turn, is the information that is given linguistically). So when you ask "How do I make up an equation", what you are... really asking... is "How do I form words" or "How do I make an argument" or "How do I say something that can be quantified", and the answer, as far as I can tell, is "You quantify, and then say what you are quantifying".

Comment: This is what I was wanting to know I think, how to go from words to formalized language (equations) thank you I’m going to give this more of a read

Answer (score 2):

Do an experiment. Now, do it again, but change just one of the parameters (e.g., the temperature, or the amount of substance, or the volume) while keeping all the other parameters the same. Now do it fifty more times, recording the results of all these experiments. Now look at your table of all the different results you got, each one with its corresponding input value. Draw a graph showing the dependence of the output on the input. Compare it to all the graphs you know about. If the graph fits one of the ones in your arsenal, congratulations! You have discovered a law of Nature.

Comment: Now that’s a good answer but how do I go from my graph to writing up an equation? Are equations inseperable from graphs? @gerrymyerson

Comment: How was for example can you make up: $$v=\frac{d}{t}$$ can it be done without doing experiments?

Comment: @Nickotine $v = d/t$ is just the definition of velocity. You take the distance traveled and divide it by the time elapsed, and that tells you how fast an object is moving.

Comment: But how do you make this equation up is what I’m trying to understand @littleO

Comment: @Nickotine If someone asked you how fast an object is moving, what would you tell them? "Really fast" or  "pretty slow"? They want a number that tells them precisely how fast the object is going. So what would you tell them? Let's say you want to specify how fast a car is allowed to travel on a certain road. How do you convey that information to a driver in a way that is precise and unambiguous?

Comment: Err you’d say, ‘Well to go from a -> b it takes x amount of time’ @littleO but then how do you get that in an equation?

Comment: @Nickotine Yes, correct; so you'd say, like, the object goes $d$ meters every $t$ seconds, or in other words the speed of the object is $d/t$ meters per second. For example, if the object moves $10$ meters every $2$ seconds, then the speed of the object is $10/2 = 5$ meters per second. If the object movies $20$ meters every $5$ seconds then its speed is $20/5 = 4$ meters per second. So $v = d/t$ seems like the natural quantity to describe how fast an object is moving.

Comment: To go from a graph to an equation you have to have a lot of experience sketching the graphs of equations. When you have that experience, you'll be able to tell whether a graph that comes from a series of experiments looks like $y=\log x$ or $y=e^{-x}$ or $y=x^2$ or $y=\sin x$ or ....

Comment: @GerryMyerson is it impossible to come up with an equation to a problem without using a graph? Or are equations dependent on graphing?

Comment: You wanted an example of how to come up with an equation. I gave you one. I never said this was the only way. Indeed, people came up with equations for thousands of years before anyone ever drew a graph. I'm not sure we know how Pythagoras came up with $a^2+b^2=c^2$ (although we do know he never wrote it that way) or how anyone came up with $C=\pi D$. I expect the details are lost in the mists of time. Still, you might get yourself a good History of Math book and settle in for a nice read.

Comment: @gerrmyerson thank you for the clarification and indeed the example was very useful